# set the behaviour of a page as dialog in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I set into a `script` tag that a jquery mobile page, must have a behaviour like a dialog beside add to the main div `data-role = dialog` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the data-rel='dialog' attribute in the script using id like

```
$('#linkToPage2').attr('data-rel','dialog');
```

Here are the examples
 http://jsfiddle.net/q4jrY/6/ and http://jsfiddle.net/reddyprasad321/q4jrY/5/